# Retrieving children from a particular parent for display on a select component

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have a parent-child domain-class relation in Grails as shown, and I want to retrieve all the children of one specific parent object in order to display them in a HTML select component for the user to pick.

```
class Parent { 
static hasMany = [children: child]
}

class child {
string name 
Parent parent
static belongsTo = [Parent]
}
```

I know I should use a Grails' select tag of the form:

```
<g:select name="user.company.id"
      from="${parent}"
      value="${user?.company.id}"
      optionKey="id" />
```

I tried doing this, but it does not seem to work:

```
<g:select name="child.id"
      from="${the parent.children}"
      optionKey="id" />
```

Any suggestions on what the correct syntax is? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Try this for a drop-down:

```
<g:select name="children"
          from="${parent.children}"
          optionKey="id" optionValue="name"/>
```

For multiple selects you can use:

```
<g:select name="children"
          from="${parent.children}"
          value="${parent.children.id}"
          optionKey="id" optionValue="name" 
          multiple="true"/>
```

Comment: doesn't work, but thanks… I've been trying to figure this out for a couple of hours and nothing

Comment: Do you have `static belongsTo = [parent: Parent]` in Child class? And how are you setting up the model, can you show the controller? @user2108393

Comment: It works for me as expected. How are you making `parent` available in the gsp from the controller. I just wanted to confirm the model sent from controller. @user2108393

Comment: parent is available trough the session object session.user I accessed other properties of the session.user in this gsp with no problems @dmahapatro

Comment: I realized what the problem is… I'm new to Grails so I just realized that the domain-classes are only accessible from their controllers and views. How can I make the parent domain class accessible in a different view? @dmahapatro

Comment: Depends on the way you [render](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Controllers/render.html) from the action method. I hope this could help.

Comment: thanks, that's very helpful… so let's say I want to make the external parent domain class available from the controller doing something like `def theShining = new Book(title: 'The Shining', author: 'Stephen King') render(view: "viewName", model: [book: theShining])` Where do these lines go in the controller?

Comment: Go through [this](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#understandingControllersAndActions) from top to bottom, you will get your answer in and around 7.1.3. Mark those docs as Grails Bible if you want to learn from scratch. Enjoy. :)

Comment: I got it to work… and kind of understand this framework a lil better now @dahapatro

Comment: @dahapatro one question, is there a way to bring the selected value in the view to  a controller function?